# Every request being sent by Firefox triggers ConnectionResetError

Tags: django, sockets, firefox

For some reason Firefox, and only Firefox is causing this problem. Django server is still functional and I'm able to navigate, but stack trace keeps appearing on terminal.

Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Start django app (python3 manage.py runserver),
2. Open client/browser(firefox) and go to localhost:8000,
3. Start making requests / clicking URLs / anything that sends a request to Django
4. Terminal stack trace:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55364)
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55366)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/orion/Desktop/Claymore/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/orion/Desktop/Claymore/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/orion/Desktop/Claymore/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/orion/Desktop/Claymore/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

For some reason Chrome and Safari do not trigger the socket / connection reset. Not sure what is happening here.

Comment: Try allowing scripts to run. By default firefox strictly blocks scripts. Change the preference of Content Blocking to **Standard** and **Allow** long-running scripts. (Although both of them are not suggested for security reasons, still you can give it try)